# Style the First Occurence of a Class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a stack of divs:

```
<div>
    <div class="meat">Some stuff</div>
    <div class="meat">Some stuff</div>
    <div class="meat">Some stuff</div>
    <div class="meat">Some stuff</div>
    <div class="dairy">Some stuff</div>
    <div class="dairy">Some stuff</div>
    <div class="dairy">Some stuff</div>
</div>
```

I need to style the first of each class, and don't have control over the html... preferably pure CSS, but jQuery would also do.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Solution 1 :** Define a specific style for elements that are not the first one :

```
.meat {
    // applies to all
}
.meat + .meat {
    // applies to those that aren't the first one
}
```

For example, if you want to color in red the first `.meat` element, do this :

```
.meat {
  color: red;
}
.meat+.meat{
  color: inherit;
}
```

[Documentation about the + pattern :](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html)

> E + F Matches any F element immediately preceded by a sibling element E.

**Solution 2 :** Use `:not` in combination with `+` and `first-child` :

```
.dairy:first-child, :not(.dairy)+.dairy {
  color: red;
}
```

This selector targets any element of class `dairy` which is either

- the first child (and thus the first of its class in the parent) or
- following another element whose class isn't `dairy`

**[Demonstration](http://jsbin.com/eNuCIGUv/1/)**

[Documentation of `:not`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/%3anot)

Notes :

- those selectors aren't available on IE8 (but not a lot of the modern web is, Google even stopped support of IE9 in GMail...).
- if you wanted to apply the same kind of rule but with possible intermediate elements, you'd use `~` instead of `+`

Comment: can you explain :not ?

Comment: what does the plus sign does in css ?

Comment: @FranciscoCorrales sibling

Comment: @FranciscoCorrales I added the documentation of the plus sign.

Comment: Thank you. But that looks weird, to apply to all, and then all-first... Can't it be done with one instruction ?

Comment: Can the downvoter explain what he didn't like ?

Comment: @FranciscoCorrales I found a "one instruction" solution :)

Comment: @dystroy ie9+....(regarding not)

Comment: shouldn't that be `~` instead of `+`?

Comment: @Mr_Green ~ is siblings which also is not immediately after . which isnt helpful in this case

Comment: @Mr_Green Depends on the goal, in fact. I'll add a notice about that.

Comment: @dystroy I was wondering why `inherit` and not `auto` ( though your solution does work)

Comment: @downvoter , again , comments are helpful

Comment: @RoyiNamir Once again it depends on the goal, but I supposed there could be a style defined in the enclosing element and OP didn't want to change it.

Comment: I don't understand the :not

Comment: @FranciscoCorrales I added an explanation of the selector using `:not` and a link to a documentation.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this : (jq solution)

`$(".meat:eq(0),.dairy:eq(0)").css('color','red');`

[image]

Comment: downvotes explnation would be great.

Comment: "preferably pure CSS". This is a CSS question. I don't get why people want to replace a simple, fast CSS selector(s) with a overweight JS lib.

Comment: @bjb568 "but jQuery would also do."

Comment: But jQuery wouldn't do as fast or clean.

Comment: That's not your problem. he is the OP and that's what he asked.

Comment: can you make this a CSS ?

Comment: It's an answer, that's why I'm not flagging it. It's not a good one, so that's why I voted down. Don't tell the OP to use bad practices, even it if it does answer his question.

Comment: You win I dont want to argue.

Comment: @bjb568, it's a valid answer don't see the reason to downvote.

Comment: But it's bad. Isn't it good->upvote bad->downvote terrible->flag?

Comment: @FranciscoCorrales  Original Poster.

Comment: why do you say it's a bad practice? @bjb568

Comment: I find your answer acceptable, can you provide a JSFiddle working ?

Comment: @FranciscoCorrales http://jsbin.com/onUyIwEK/3/edit

Comment: Well I find your solution pretty simple, and easy to understand and edit...

Comment: @FranciscoCorrales I told you. "\"preferably pure CSS\". This is a CSS question. I don't get why people want to replace a simple, fast CSS selector(s) with a overweight JS lib. – bjb568 8 hours ago"